# How to just skip an element when building new list?

Tags: j

```
data =: '"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH"`

   ];._1 data
MARY     
,        
PATRICIA 
,        
LINDA    
,        
BARBARA  
,        
ELIZABETH
(one more blank line here)
```

So I want just skip every second line:

```
   ]`(0&#);._1 data
MARY     

PATRICIA 

LINDA    

BARBARA  

ELIZABETH
(one more blank line here)
```

Doesn't work as I thought.
And I encounter this situation quite often. For example when using code like this:

```
]`(Do nothing. Just skip. Just SKIP!!!)@.(some condition)
```

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. Is parsing a string of comma-separated values what you're trying to do? Or are you trying to get every other row of an array? Or something else? For example, `0 2 4 6 8 { array` will get you the rows, but that's probably not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Initially I wanted to parse the string. But later it becomes just an example to more general question.

Comment: @roman, as @bob hints, selecting elements with `#`,  `{` or `^:` is more appropriate for what you have in mind. Using `v @. c` means that you have to do _something_ with all input elements. `v ^: c` is closer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way, by appending a `,','` (important that this is a list and not an atom) after removing the last LF and then using Cut `;.` again this time based on the end value.

```
   ( ];._2) @: ((,','),~ }:) @: (];._1) data

MARY     

PATRICIA 

LINDA    

BARBARA  

ELIZABETH
```

The blank lines are not really blanks but an artifact of the shape.

```
   $(];._2) @: ((,','),~ }:) @: (];._1) data 
5 1 9
```

Insert Append `,/` cleans this up

```
,/ @: (];._2) @: ((,','),~ }:) @: (];._1) data 
    MARY     
    PATRICIA 
    LINDA    
    BARBARA  
    ELIZABETH
       $,/ @: (];._2) @: ((,','),~ }:) @: (];._1) data
    5 9
```

This doesn't really solve your "do nothing" issue with skipping, but there is irony in wanting to do nothing and at the same time wanting to SKIP! Skipping would be doing something, wouldn't it? That might suggest another approach such as Copy `#` may be better than Agenda `@.` but one would have to know the specific case.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip every second element of a list, you can use `(_2 {.\ ])`

In other words: break the list up into pairs and get the first element of each pair.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options to filter out every 2nd element of a list:

```
   mylist=: ];._1 data
   (#~ 2 -.@| i.@#) mylist   NB. retain even indexed items
MARY     
PATRICIA 
LINDA    
BARBARA  
ELIZABETH
   (_2 {.\ ]) mylist         NB. get first item of pairs
MARY     
PATRICIA 
LINDA    
BARBARA  
ELIZABETH
```

A couple of options to parse this data:

```
   > '","' splitstring }. }: data
MARY     
PATRICIA 
LINDA    
BARBARA  
ELIZABETH

   require 'csv'
   > (',' ; '"') fixdsv data,LF
MARY     
PATRICIA 
LINDA    
BARBARA  
ELIZABETH
```